# Reference an int from codebehind in markup (.Net)

Tags: .net, asp.net, markup, code-behind

I have an aspx-Page with an int in Codebehind:

```
private const int id = 11;
```

And in Markup I have

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT Name FROM [StatusOption] WHERE StatusId = 11">
```

I would like to reference the id from codebehind in the markup, so that I only have to change it in codebehind when necessary. Is it possible and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set the desired value in the [`SqlDataSource.Selecting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting.aspx) event.

I added a new select parameter to your data source - `statusId` and set a value to it in the `SqlDataSource_Selecting` event handler:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Name FROM [StatusOption] WHERE StatusId = @statusId"
    OnSelecting="SqlDataSource_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="statusId" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

and then in code-behind:

```
protected void SqlDataSource_Selecting(
    object sender, 
    SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@statusId"].Value = id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The command has to be e.Command.Parameters["@statusId"].Value = id; though ;)